# Why is maven-jlink-plugin crashing? What's the illegal argument?

Tags: java, maven, jlink

After upgrading to Java 10 (from Java 8), I want to test the new linker, so I started using maven-jlink-plugin by adding this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jlink-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha-1</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

and specifying:

```
<packaging>jlink</packaging>
```

I don't even know if this should be enough, but it certainly isn't working and the documentation seems to focus on projects with multiple modules. Mine only has one. When I run `mvn package` I get:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink (default-jlink) @ dashmanserver ---
[INFO] Toolchain in maven-jlink-plugin: jlink [ C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\jlink.exe ]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.988 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-30T13:37:38+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink (default-jlink) on project dashmanserver: Execution default-jlink of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink failed.: IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

The full output of the error, when running `mvn package -X` is this:

```
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=725468, ConflictMarker.markTime=223703, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=262, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=185280, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=54930, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=97, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=4101786, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCou
nt=204, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=304630505, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=5305398}
[WARNING] The artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.10.Final has been relocated to org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.10.Final
[DEBUG] tech.flexpoint:dashmanserver:jlink:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]    tech.flexpoint:dashmancommon:jar:1.0.0-beta.11:compile
[DEBUG]       org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile (version managed from 3.0.1-b10)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]          org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]          org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile (version managed from 2.9.6)
[DEBUG]          com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile (version managed from 2.9.0)
[DEBUG]          com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6:compile (version managed from 2.9.6)
[DEBUG]       com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.6:compile (version managed from 2.9.6)
[DEBUG]       com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.6:compile (version managed from 2.9.6)
[DEBUG]       com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.6:compile (version managed from 2.9.6)
[DEBUG]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 2.0.3.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]          org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 2.0.3.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]             ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile (version managed from 1.2.3)
[DEBUG]                ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile (version managed from 1.2.3)
[DEBUG]             org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile (version managed from 2.10.0)
[DEBUG]                org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile (version managed from 2.10.0)
[DEBUG]             org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile (version managed from 1.7.25)
[DEBUG]          javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile (version managed from 1.3.2)
[DEBUG]          org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime (version managed from 1.19)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 2.0.3.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 2.0.3.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]          org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.31:compile (version managed from 8.5.31)
[DEBUG]          org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.31:compile (version managed from 8.5.31)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[DEBUG]       com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.9:compile (version managed from 2.7.9)
[DEBUG]          org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile (version managed from 1.7.25)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]          org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 2.0.3.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]          org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile (version managed from 1.8.13)
[DEBUG]       org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.17.Final:compile (version managed from 5.2.17.Final) (exclusions managed)
[DEBUG]          org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile (version managed from 1.0.0.Final)
[DEBUG]          org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[DEBUG]          antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile (version managed from 2.7.7)
[DEBUG]          org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[DEBUG]          dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile (version managed from 1.6.1)
[DEBUG]          org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 2.0.8.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]          org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 2.0.8.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]          org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[DEBUG]       org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.6.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.6.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 2.0.3.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]          org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 2.0.3.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.0.5:compile (version managed from 1.0.5)
[DEBUG]          org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.10:compile
[DEBUG]          org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[DEBUG]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 2.0.3.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 2.0.3.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]    org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.2.jre7:compile
[DEBUG]    org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.59:compile
[DEBUG]    javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[DEBUG]    javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]    org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.10.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile (version managed from 3.3.2.Final)
[DEBUG]       com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile (version managed from 1.3.4)
[DEBUG]    javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:5.1.3:compile
[DEBUG]    io.sentry:sentry-spring:jar:1.7.5:compile
[DEBUG]       io.sentry:sentry:jar:1.7.5:compile
[DEBUG]    com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-agent:jar:4.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[DEBUG]    javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:test
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:test (version managed from 2.0.3.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:test (version managed from 2.0.3.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test (version managed from 2.4.0)
[DEBUG]          net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[DEBUG]             net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[DEBUG]                org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[DEBUG]       junit:junit:jar:4.12:test (version managed from 4.12)
[DEBUG]       org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test (version managed from 3.9.1)
[DEBUG]       org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0:test (version managed from 2.15.0)
[DEBUG]          net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.11:test (version managed from 1.7.9)
[DEBUG]          net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.11:test (version managed from 1.7.9)
[DEBUG]          org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[DEBUG]       org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test (version managed from 1.3)
[DEBUG]       org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test (version managed from 1.3)
[DEBUG]       org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test (version managed from 1.5.0)
[DEBUG]          com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[DEBUG]       org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]          org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:test (version managed from 5.0.7.RELEASE)
[DEBUG]       org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test (version managed from 2.5.1)
[DEBUG]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:test
[DEBUG]       org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 5.0.6.RELEASE)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink (default-jlink) @ dashmanserver ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink from plugin realm ClassRealm[extension>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ef04b5]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) bindServices = false
[DEBUG]   (f) finalName = dashmanserver-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) ignoreSigningInformation = false
[DEBUG]   (f) noHeaderFiles = false
[DEBUG]   (f) noManPages = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Dashman\code\dashmanserver\target
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectoryImage = C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Dashman\code\dashmanserver\target\maven-jlink
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: tech.flexpoint:dashmanserver:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Dashman\code\dashmanserver\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@1e0895f5
[DEBUG]   (f) stripDebug = false
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Toolchain in maven-jlink-plugin: jlink [ C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\jlink.exe ]
[DEBUG]  Parent: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1
[DEBUG]  jmodsFolder: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\jmods
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.367 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-30T13:34:04+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink (default-jlink) on project dashmanserver: Execution default-jlink of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink failed.: IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink (default-jlink) on project dashmanserver: Execution default-jlink of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-jlink of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.AsmModuleInfoParser.parse (AsmModuleInfoParser.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.AsmModuleInfoParser.getModuleDescriptor (AsmModuleInfoParser.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager.resolvePaths (LocationManager.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.jlink.JLinkMojo.preparePaths (JLinkMojo.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.jlink.JLinkMojo.execute (JLinkMojo.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Am I missing some more configuration? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is done by fix only a few hours ago https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJLINK-19 which fixes this isssue...

Comment: But not yet released...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I needed to add a new version of asm to the dependencies of maven-jlink-plugin:~

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jlink-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha-1</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version> <!-- Use newer version of ASM -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin snapshot solves the problem. It can be used by updating the pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jlink-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha-2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <!-- configuration elements goes here -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```